# Angular scope variables and plugins scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to do several things, and with all of them I am facing the same problem. I want to access some angular variables inside other libs, for example:

I have a directive, that does this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], {
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
  },
  center: center
});
```

In this case, center is a variable declared right before map, but center is not available inside the "Map"...

In the same way..

I have a directive with this:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
  $.datepicker.regional["pt-BR"];
  element.datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      scope.model = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      scope.showDp = false;
    }
  });
}
```

"model" and "showDp" are variables from my scope, scope is accessible out of datepicker's function, but on the "onSelect" I don't have nothing, how can I do in both cases?

Comment: Unless you show us more code that reveals where 'center' is declared. There is very little anyone can do to help

Comment: Maybe scope is isolated, make sure u passing scope in directive if u trying to cross access with directive and controller.

Comment: @Neha Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case you could do something like this -

```
var center = 'something';
var constructWith = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
    center: center
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], constructWith);
```

---

As for the second case, try something like this -

```
var myFunc = function () {
   // if $(this) doesn't work use $(element)
   scope.model = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
   scope.showDp = false;
};
$.datepicker.regional["pt-BR"];
element.datepicker({onSelect: myFunc});
```

Comment: You are a genius *-* Thank you VERY much :)))))))

Comment: so I upvoted your question and I think you should have voting privileges now.. Now upvote me too! :P